# merge_asof multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I know that a similar question has been asked before. However, my question is slightly different. I am trying to get the functionality of the merge_asof across multiple columns. Here is the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,5,10]\
                    ,'business'['FRC','FRC','FRC']\
                    ,'left_val':['a','b','c']})
right = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,6]\
                    ,'business':['ED','ED','ED','ED']\
                    ,'right_val':[1,2,3,6]})
pd.merge_asof(left,right,on='a',direction='forward')
```

the output that I get is:

[image]

I would like to include business in the join as well. **So , the right_val and business of the join should show NaN for all values.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need parameter `by` in [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

> **by** : column name or list of column names
>   Match on these columns before performing merge operation.

```
print (pd.merge_asof(left,right,on='a',direction='forward', by='business'))
    a business left_val  right_val
0   1      FRC        a        NaN
1   5      FRC        b        NaN
2  10      FRC        c        NaN
```